# Probability and Big-O notation

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $m$ be a positive integer, and let $p(m)$ be the probability that a number chosen
with uniform distribution from $\{1,... , m\}$ is divisible by either $4$, $5$ or $6$.

Show that $$p(m) = \frac{14}{30} + O\left(\frac1m\right)$$

What I have done so far :

number of elements divisible by $4 = \frac m4$
number of elements divisible by $5 = \frac m5$
number of elements divisible by $6 = \frac m6$
$P($choosing an element from {1, ... , m }$)$ $= \frac 1m$

Using all the above values in the inclusion-exclusion principle I got the number of elements divisible by either $4$, $5$ and $6$. But I don't know that to do next.

Comment: Consider that $m/4$ is not always an integer.  Can you bound the sum of the "errors" by a constant?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on how to get the $O(\frac1m)$ part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number  of elements of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ that are divisible by $k$ is $\lfloor m/k \rfloor$ instead of $m/k$.  The two quantities are related by $m = k \cdot \lfloor m/k \rfloor + m \bmod k$, so that their difference is less than $1$.  If you got the $14/30$, it means that you applied inclusion/exclusion correctly, but to the $m/k$'s.  If you account for the residues in your computation, you should get a term whose absolute value is bounded by $C/m$, where $C$ is a small positive integer.

Comment: I'm not able to get $\frac{14}{30}$ either. Please help.

Comment: If a number is divisible by 12 but not by 60, then it's counted twice if your count the numbers divisible by 4, 5, or 6, because it's divisible by both 4 and 6.  Likewise for numbers divisible by 20 and 30, but not by 60...

Comment: But wouldn't $m$ always remain in the expression? How is it that $\frac{14}{30}$ does not contain $m$?

Comment: I have done this:   $\frac m4 + \frac m5 + \frac m6 - \frac{m}{20} - \frac{m}{30}-   \frac{m}{24} + \frac{m}{120}$

Comment: Suppose $m$ is very large so that you can neglect the residues.  Then the number of elements divisible by $4$ is very close to $m/4$.  This means that the probability of drawing a number that is divisible by $4$ is very close to $1/4$.  Similarly for the probability of drawing a number divisible by $5$, $6$, ... $60$.

Comment: I see.  A number divisible by both $4$ and $6$ is divisible by the GCD of $4$ and $6$, which is $12$.   For example, $36$ is divisible by both $4$ and $6$, but not by $24$.

Comment: I obviously meant LCM of $4$ and $6$.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm so embarrassed! How does the sum of the residues come to $\frac Cm$ ?

Comment: Because you have 7 residues (4,5,6,12,20,30,60), all less than 1.  Some are added and some are subtracted.  When you divide by $m$, they add up to a quantity that is not exacly $C/m$, but is bounded by it.